# Effect of robots.txt

Tags: search, web-crawler, robots.txt

I understand that naming a file to disallow in robots.txt will stop well behaved crawlers from scanning that file's content, but does it (also) stop the file being listed as a search result?

Answer (score 0):

No, both Google and Bing will not stop indexing the file just because it appears in robots.txt:

> A robots.txt file tells search engine crawlers which URLs the crawler can access on your site. This is used mainly to avoid overloading your site with requests; it is not a mechanism for keeping a web page out of Google. To keep a web page out of Google, block indexing with noindex or password-protect the page.

https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/robots/intro

> It is important to understand that this not by definition implies that a page that is not crawled also will not be indexed. To see how to prevent a page from being indexed see [this topic](https://www.bing.com/webmasters/help/?topicid=37c07477).

https://www.bing.com/webmasters/help/how-to-create-a-robots-txt-file-cb7c31ec